# Seeking building footprints for informal settlement in Tanzania?

Tags: data, tanzania

How/where can I find building footprint for Mwanza Area in Tanzania?

The specific area is more informal so no data on OpenStreetMap. The KML file are in the link below.

http://dropbox.com/s/9psrasoq74wariu/New%20polygons.kml?dl=0

Comment: Are the buildings visible on OpenStreetMap?

Comment: No buildings on open street, its an informal settlement

Comment: The link is 404.

Answer (score 2):

Data from OpenStreetMap can be downloaded and used according to the very liberal license terms. The Overpass API site can let you select an area and download selected parts of OSM (roads, buildings, parks etc).

I constructed a query which I think is the right part of the world, and selects the building data. If you go here:

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hIt

it should run the query and then you can use the "Export" button to download in a GIS format such as GeoJSON which you can load into QGIS or (maybe) ArcGIS.

Comment: The area am looking for is more of an informal settlement no data on open street. Here's a link to the polygons: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9psrasoq74wariu/New%20polygons.kml?dl=0